# Creating a Python CentOS ISO

Tags: python, linux, centos

What is the best approach to package a python based application on a bare bones CentOS/Linux operation system and then create an iso image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a kickstart based install script and package the result into an iso. 
This will allow you to install CentOS from scratch, including any additional applications you want to install in the base installation.

This should lead you in the right direction:

http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/35-linux/128-building-a-custom-centos-6-kickstart-disc-part-1

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to package a pyton-based application is to create an RPM out of it (for CentOS).

You can read some information about it [here](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html).

Creating an ISO that includes your package for CentOS is described in [CentOS official documentation](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/ch-kickstart2.html). As monkut mentioned, kickstart is the way to go.

Alternatively you can just [create a repository](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalRepos) containing your RPM and provide people with instructions on how to add you repository and install your package.